# How to list all existing passkeys on macOS?

Tags: macos, icloud, keychain, passkey

I'd like to list all accounts with passkeys (Webauthn credentials) stored in my iCloud Keychain.

- **I don't need to *export* the passkeys** (although I'd like to be able to, but this is a different question).
- I merely want to have a **list of all accounts that have a stored passkey.** It can be either via command-line, system API, or a GUI app.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the macOS Keychain application from the Application Utility folder not show you what you need?

Comment: @LouisLangholtz no, I haven't found any passkeys or webauthn in Keychain Access. It shows normal passwords but not anything related to passkeys.